# if cell contains specific text, copy whole column

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to filter column 9 within the table1 that contain a specific text in A2. I want to copy the whole column and past it in a new sheet then run text to column to separate the copied column.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim filterinput As Range
Dim filterrange As Range

Set filterinput = Range("A2")
Set filterrange = Range("Table1")

filterrange.AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="*" & filterinput & "*", _
visibledropdown:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you copying Column A or Column L?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Sheets(2).UsedRange.autofilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array("Goods", "Services"), VisibleDropDown:=False, Operator:=xlFilterValues

' ###For Column A
Sheets(2).UsedRange.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'###For Column L 
Sheets(2).UsedRange.Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```